# Is there a way to open an HTML5 video in the Native Android Video Player?

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-video, apk

I am using Cordova to create an APK.
The Android WebView does not allow scrubbing of HTML5 video.
Is possible to open my app's video in Android's Native Video Player.

The HTML is simple:
`<video src="video.mp4"></video>`

For the scrubbing issue, I have tried to render the video as an iframe and embedded element but neither have worked.
I have also tried to invoke JS commands on the video. While these work in my browser, they do not work when exported to an APK.

I have also researched related SO posts but found no solidifying answers.
How would you make a call to another app on the device?
I read about using **Intent** but that appears to be a Native solution, such as developing the app in Android Studio.

Comment: [Exoplayer project is a recommended way to play videos on Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer), and there is a [cordova plugin project](https://github.com/frontyard/cordova-plugin-exoplayer) which may suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use cordova-plugin-media.

read this documentation https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/reference/cordova-plugin-media/index.html

additionally you can also use any freely available jquery media player plugins

for eg. https://videojs.com/

Comment: Thanks Riya, I will explore the cordova-plugin-media documentation. I have tried using videoJS before but Cordova just ignored in on compile. Have you had any success with either of these methods?

Comment: Hi, Yes I have been using them in 2 of my apps. One got published just 10 days ago

Comment: I was able to get audio to play from a video and create button elements to skip forward/backward but have yet to be able to display the video. Just the audio plays. Would you be able to share some example code? 

Here is my repo:
https://github.com/chadLinthicum/Cordova-Video-Test.git

Comment: Hi, are you going to load the video urls dynamically? ajax? loop? or a static url? lemme know as I have found one more light weight script...very simple to use

Comment: They are local to the repo. I am unfamiliar with those terms you mention, can you elaborate? You can see in my script.js, I am assigning it here:
let src = "file:///android_asset/www/media/demo.mp4";

Comment: ok great I just wanted to have that url.. i.e. the local path "file:///android_asset/www/media/". Will try to post in your repo...else here...just give me couple of hours as I am here for finding solutions to my own troubles as of now.

alternatively you can use this url as it is way to simple to setup 
https://videojs.com/guides/setup/

I used the same guidelines and I use media plugin only for playing audios. For videos it's better to use external plugins and customize them rather than making your own player (just a suggestion)

Comment: My main problem is that I cannot scrub/seek through video in the cordova APK build, even when using VideoJS. It's an issue with the Android Webview. The closest I've come is using cordova-plugin-media to seek through a video's audio, but I cannot figure out how to get the video to appear.

Comment: I've recorded a video showing the issue. You can see the browser works fine but when I attempt to srub/seek from the Cordova build APK, the feature is broken. You can see I am using Video JS as well. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNJ0QBWC_Yo&ab_channel=Metalvain

Comment: It's surprising. I emulate directly on device and it works fine for me. Lemme dig through emulator once. Will let you know in few hours.

Comment: You ran the APK on your personal device an it worked? I have tried 3 Android devices, all of which do not have working srub/seeking.

Comment: Also, did you say you used cordova-plugin-media to open a video in Android's Native Video Player? Do you have a code example?